# Dual monitors with VGA and HDMI on Intel HD Graphics 4600 with correct screen resolution (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

I am running Windows 7. My computer has an Intel HD Graphics 4600 with the latest drivers. I am trying to run dual monitors with two Asus VS228 monitors. The ideal resolution for this is 1920x1080. Currently, I have one monitor hooked into VGA and the other into HDMI. The HDMI monitor will run at 1920x1080, whereas the VGA monitor will not. These are my only options:

1600x1200
1280x1024
etc.

How can I get dual screen monitors with the correct resolution on each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in this case ended up being that there was a problem with the VGA cable being used. Switching out the VGA cable allowed for the correct screen resolution. The problem with the VGA cable is unknown yet.